# Kendo Grid to Display Data in the Grid with HTML Code in Angular

Tags: angular, kendo-grid

I am using `Kendo Grid` with `Angular`

I have changed the Current Kendo Grid from Client-Side-Paging to Server-Side-Paging and the source is as below...

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/server-side-paging-in-kendo-grid-for-angular-2/

Old code which works with Client-Side-Paging is as below...

```
<kendo-grid [data]="usersDataView | async" [height]="425" [pageSize]="pageSize" [skip]="skip"
        [pageable]="true" [kendoGridBinding]="data" (pageChange)="onPageChange($event)" [sort]="state.sort" 
        (selectionChange)="selectionChanged($event)" [groupable]="false" [group]="state.group" 
        [columnMenu]="true" [resizable]="true">
<kendo-grid-column showSelectAll="true" [width]="60" [minResizableWidth]="60">
    <ng-template kendoGridHeaderTemplate let-column let-columnIndex="columnIndex">
      <input type="checkbox" (click)="SetAllSelected($event)" />
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template kendoGridCellTemplate let-dataItem>
      <input type="checkbox" [checked]="dataItem.selected"
        [attr.disabled]="dataItem.deviceName !== null  ? true : null" (click)=SetSelectedItem(dataItem) />
    </ng-template>
  </kendo-grid-column>
  <kendo-grid-column field="userName" title={{translations.USER_NAME}} filter="text" [filterable]="true"
    headerClass="kendoColumn">
    <ng-template kendoGridCellTemplate let-dataItem>
      <a *ngIf="dataItem.userStatus === 0"
        [routerLink]="['/users/details/'+dataItem.userd]">{{dataItem.userName}}</a>
      <span *ngIf="dataItem.userStatus === 1">{{dataItem.userName}}</span>
    </ng-template>
  </kendo-grid-column>
</kendo-grid>
```

I just don't want to touch this code and just want to change the result of `usersDataView` which is changed from `GridDataResult` to `Observable<GridDataResult>`. The data is coming under `dataGridResult.data` of `usersDataView`.

[image: DataGridResult]

How to point the `dataGridResult.data` in the HTML so that Grid would be populated?

**EDIT**

In the code sample, it is created dynamically as below...

```
<kendo-grid-column *ngFor="let col of columns" [field]="col.field"></kendo-grid-column>
```

It works perfectly with the above `*ngFor` statement.

But the Old code is having lot of HTML code, I don't want to disturb that. Any possible way of doing this?

Currently, I am getting the below error when I use `ngFor` in `HTML`.

[image: ngFor]

Comment: Do you have any errors after changing the data?

Comment: I am not getting any errors even after changing the data.

Comment: I am curious on how to use let-dataItem with `usersDataView.dataGridResult.data` to get the data in the Grid.

Comment: Edited the Question. Please have a look at it.

Comment: Something like combination of both dynamic and HTML is also Ok for me. Like using ForLoop in HTML and adding additional element logic would be helpful for me.

Comment: I have used `<div *ngFor="let col of usersDataView">` in the HTML and trying to pull the records and it is fetching all the columns with error as attached to the Question.

Comment: I am using `*ngIf="col.field == UserName" field="col.field` to display `UserName` column in the Grid.